# Plot label at each vertex and intersection of a hexagram in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, geometry

I'm trying to produce the below picture of "A hexagram or 6-pointed star polygon in which numbers are placed at each of the six vertices and six intersections".

[image]

Below is my code so far. I'm stuck trying to find the vertices of the hexagon to plot the numbers there.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

def plot_hexagram_with_numbers(side_length):
    # Calculate the coordinates for the vertices of the hexagram
    vertices = []
    mu_hexagon = 360 / 6
    for i in range(6):
        angle_rad = math.radians(i * mu_hexagon)
        x = side_length * math.cos(angle_rad)
        y = side_length * math.sin(angle_rad)
        vertices.append((x, y))

    # Create a list of triangles' vertices for the hexagram
    triangles = []
    for i in range(6):
        triangle = [vertices[i], vertices[(i + 2) % 6], vertices[(i + 4) % 6]]
        triangles.append(triangle)

    # Plot the hexagram's triangles
    for triangle in triangles:
        x_coords, y_coords = zip(*triangle)
        plt.plot(x_coords, y_coords, 'b-')

    # Add numbers at each vertex and intersection of the hexagram
    label_distance = side_length / 20  # Adjust this value as needed
    for i in range(6):
        x, y = vertices[i]
        # cant figure out how to find the edges/intersections :( 

    # Set axis equal and show the plot
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.show()
```

This is the image the above code produces:

[image]

Comment: I just realized, perhaps the rotation is an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your triangles are not closed and you therefore have more than two triangles (which an hexagram is) in `triangles`. You should build the complete triangles, this way you can even generalize your code for any size of pointed stars (as long as it is a multiple of 3).

I used [shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to compute intersections:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from shapely import Polygon, get_coordinates

def plot_hexagram_with_numbers(side_length, nb_points=6):
    if nb_points % 3:
        raise ValueError("nb_points must be a multiple of 3")
    # Calculate the coordinates for the vertices of the hexagram
    vertices = []
    mu_hexagon = 360 / nb_points
    for i in range(nb_points):
        angle_rad = math.radians(i * mu_hexagon)
        x = side_length * math.cos(angle_rad)
        y = side_length * math.sin(angle_rad)
        vertices.append((x, y))

    # Create a list of triangles' vertices and plot triangles
    triangles = []
    nb_triangles = nb_points//3
    for i in range(nb_triangles):
        triangle = [vertices[i], vertices[i + nb_triangles], vertices[i + 2*nb_triangles], vertices[i]]
        plt.plot(*zip(*triangle), 'b-')
        triangles.append(Polygon(triangle))

    # computing intersections
    intersections = [] 
    for i in range(nb_triangles):
        for j in range(i+1, nb_triangles):
            intersections.extend(get_coordinates(triangles[i].intersection(triangles[j]))[:-1])

    # Add numbers at each vertex and intersection of the hexagram
    for i, (x,y) in enumerate(vertices + intersections, start=1):
        plt.annotate(i, (x,y))

    # Set axis equal and show the plot
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.show()
```

Output (default, `nb_points=6`):

[image]

Output (`nb_points=9`):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using sympy. With sympy you can create two overlapping triangles as `Polygon` objects. The sympy `Polygon` objects have an `intersection` method that will return the points of intersection, if they exist. See the [documentation here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/geometry/polygons.html).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sp

vertices1 = [(0,0), (1,0), (0.5, 3**0.5/2)]
vertices2 = [(0,0.6), (1,0.6), (0.5, 0.6-3**0.5/2)]

sp_triangle1 = sp.Polygon(*vertices1)
sp_triangle2 = sp.Polygon(*vertices2)

intersections = sp_triangle1.intersection(sp_triangle2)
intersections = [(float(p.x), float(p.y)) for p in intersections]

all_points = intersections + vertices1 + vertices2
print(all_points)

triangle1 = plt.Polygon(vertices1, fill=False)
triangle2 = plt.Polygon(vertices2, fill=False)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_patch(triangle1)
ax.add_patch(triangle2)
for n, point in enumerate(all_points, 1):
    ax.annotate(n, point)
ax.set_xlim(-0.25, 1.25)
ax.set_ylim(-0.4, 1)
ax.set_aspect(1)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Note that I've used the odd sequence of labels used in the example figure posted in the question, just in case that the precise sequence is one of the requirements of an assignment.

[image]

Re the following code, points and anchors for the labels are placed on circles of different radii, using simple trigonometry.

There is a bit of preparation before plotting because I want to align all the label as nicely as possible, and I want to respect the odd numbering of vertices and intersections.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.rcParams['figure.constrained_layout.use'] = True
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 150

R = 100
angles = np.linspace(0, 7, 8)*np.pi/3+np.pi/2
x = np.cos(angles)*R ; y = np.sin(angles)*R

l, c, r = 'left center right'.split()
b, c, t = 'bottom center top'.split()
positions = [
    {'ha':c, 'va':b}, {'ha':r, 'va':t}, {'ha':r, 'va':b}, # left vertices
    {'ha':c, 'va':t}, {'ha':l, 'va':b}, {'ha':l, 'va':t}, # right vertices
    {'ha':l, 'va':t}, {'ha':l, 'va':c}, {'ha':l, 'va':b}, # left intersections
    {'ha':r, 'va':b}, {'ha':r, 'va':c}, {'ha':r, 'va':t}, # right intersections
    ]
labels = '6 5 4 10 8 3 7 9 2 12 1 11'.split()

ax = plt.subplot()
ax.set_aspect(1)

plt.plot(x[0::2], y[0::2], color='k', lw=3, solid_capstyle='round')
plt.plot(x[1::2], y[1::2], color='k', lw=3, solid_capstyle='round')

n = 0
# place labels of vertices a little bit outside
R1 = R*1.07
x = np.cos(angles)*R1 ; y = np.sin(angles)*R1
for X, Y in zip(x[:6], y[:6]):
    ax.text(X, Y, labels[n], **positions[n], fontsize='large')
    n += 1

# place the labels for the intersections at the distance of 
# each triangle side from centre, i.e., d = 0.5 R
R2 = R*0.50
x = np.cos(angles+np.pi/6)*R2 ; y = np.sin(angles+np.pi/6)*R2
for X, Y in zip(x[:6], y[:6]):
    ax.text(X, Y, labels[n], **positions[n], fontsize='large')
    n += 1

# no distractions    
ax.set_frame_on(0)
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])

plt.show()
```

Comment: was wonering could you explain this part "angles = np.linspace(0, 7, 8)*np.pi/3+np.pi/2" ?

Comment: I was trying to get it working like angles = np.linspace(0, self.num_points, self.num_points+1) * np.pi / self.num_points so I could make n sided shape(s) but the polygon is never closed

Comment: @ReedJones `+np.pi/2` because I want to start at the top, `np.pi/3` because I'm simplifying `2π/n_vertices`, `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7` (what comes from `linspace(...)`) is one more than what (apparently) is strictly requested because, as you've found, the polygons otherwise do not close.  ፨፨፨፨፨፨ Beware even number of vertices is different from odd, and for `n_vertices > 6` you have different ways to connect the vertices, e.g., for n=7 you can connect every second or every third vertex, and the starry graphs are different.